# Returning specific element from list

Tags: java

Hi i want to retrieve only the name of students from list, i used filter method but it returns `boolean`,so is there any other method to do so?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Student> students=new LinkedList<>();
        students.add(new Student("Add","Nitkons",01));
        students.add(new Student("Nina","Adinson",02));
        students.add(new Student("Mick","McDonald",05));
        students.add(new Student("Anna","Lavrova",04));


        //doesnt work
        Stream<Student> x=students.stream().filter(s->{return s.getName()});

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need map :

```
Stream<String> names = students.stream().map(Student::getName);
```

And to collect the names to a List :

```
List<String> names = students.stream().map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```